# xml in xml file conversion

Tags: xml

I have a huge xml file, and some fields texts are in reality large chunks of xml, written in block of converted codes like the following:

```
&lt;RESPONSE_DATA&gt;
    &lt;RESULT&gt;
        &lt;BLOCK&gt;
 ....
        &lt;/BLOCK&gt;
    &lt;/RESULT&gt;
&lt;/RESPONSE_DATA&gt;
```

I was wondering if there is some ready available tools or libraries to convert that into proper xml. Anything would do really, java/c# or other code, or any standalone tool.

thank you

Comment: All you have to do is replace each &lt; with < and &gt; with >.  Then load it into an XMLDocument.  Did I miss something?

Comment: is that all what is required to change in xml? are < and > the only restricted characters?

Comment: Given the example you have above, yeah, its that easy.

Comment: There might be other encoded characters in there. Like `&quot;`. Or a numeric character entity.

Comment: @DJQuimby (I included in the example ... to keep it generic) I'm interested in a library or tool that takes care of all situations. Thanks svick I suspected other possibilities could exist.

Comment: I just thought about this - what if we have xml, which has another xml, which has another xml, which has another xml inside it which includes the original xml file again...

Comment: "Huge" for some people means 10Mb, for other people it means 10Gb. There's no point telling us it's huge without giving us a number.

Comment: @VladLazarenko, it's XML all the way down!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you parse the whole XML document and access this value, any XML parser should return it properly decoded. I'm pretty sure the ones in .Net do.

Answer (score 2):

When the XML parser sees input like this:

```
<p>
&lt;RESPONSE_DATA&gt;
    &lt;RESULT&gt;
        &lt;BLOCK&gt;
 ....
        &lt;/BLOCK&gt;
    &lt;/RESULT&gt;
&lt;/RESPONSE_DATA&gt;
</p>
```

it will present the application with a text node whose content is

```
<RESPONSE>
  <RESULT>
     <BLOCK>
 ....
     </BLOCK>
  </RESULT>
</RESPONSE>
```

The "readily available tool or library" that can handle this is an XML parser. When you have escaped XML nested inside XML, you need two parsing passes: the first parse extracts the nested XML as a string-with-angle-brackets, which you then pass to another XML parser to analyse its structure.